# Python sklearn OneHotEncoding categorical and sometimes repeated values

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

This is my problem with sklearn's OneHotEncoder. 
with an array `a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,22]` i.e ALL UNIQUE of `a.shape=[10,1]` (after `reshape(-1,1)`, a [10,10] matrix of OneHotEncoded values is returned.

```
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.]])
```

But with an array like `a = [1,2,2,4,4,6,7,8,9,22]` i.e NON UNIQUE of `a.shape=[10,1]` (after `reshape(-1,1)`, a [10,8] matrix of OneHotEncoded values is returned.

```
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

But I cannot use this as my input placeholder expects a [10,10] matrix as input. Can anyone help me handle non-unique values in sklearn's OneHotEncoder?

P.S Adding the parameter n_values= 10 gives an error saying `ValueError: Feature out of bounds for n_values=10`

Answer (score 1):

Do you know all the values your categorical feature can take? If so, you can do something like this:

```
enc = OneHotEncoder()   
enc.fit(np.asarray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,22]).reshape(-1, 1)) #fit your encoder to the values
data_for_encoding =  np.asarray([1,2,2,4,4,6,7,8,9,22]).reshape(-1, 1) #your data
sparse_matrix = enc.transform(data_for_encoding) #encoded data
```